# Mass delete from jasper server

Tags: jasperserver

I want to Remove all the PDF files that reside in the `reports output` folder in one go there are about 1000 files it will not be easy to delete the files one by one.

Comment: I tried rest_v2 delete with wild cards in the URIs. It didn't work. One clue I have is the following: jaspersoft studio is able to search by name and type (right-click server node > search). It must be using rest_v2 api. If you can intercept the rest calls, you can get which parameters the studio posts to the server. If the response is a difficult-to-parse json object, then we are out of luck with easy solutions. Maybe I will consider this alternative - put all pdf files in a single folder and delete/recreate it.

Comment: Oh and if you just want to do it one time. Then, you could just login to the server as jasperadmin search, select all and delete.

Comment: As i told you there are many files i am not sure how many but in 10000+ and there is no option of select all, you need to scroll down untill all are shown on screen and then delete. A lot of manual work. :(

Comment: Is deleting the folder containing the pdfs an option for you?